# Is it safe to run external commands such as awk, sed, grep etc in C?

Tags: c, linux, security, pipe

I am running a command that gives a string as output which I read in my C code using popen().

The command I pass to popen() is something like this:

```
mypipe = popen("some_cmd | awk '{print $2}'", "r");
```

Essentially this makes it simpler and avoids further parsing in C. I am concerned whether it's the right thing to do here. Of course, I can do the same with awk:

```
mypipe = popen("some_cmd", "r");
```

and then use strtok()  to parse the string I want.

My question is whether using awk (or similar) to parse the pipe output is considered unsafe as in the above example considering I am going to run an external command anyway (using popen()). Will it ever cause any issue?

Comment: I don't see what bad can happen. In the worst case, the computer, running your program, will not have `awk` installed. Also, depends on this `some_cmd` - is it hardcoded, or it's user input? Because if it's the second, the user can do really bad things to the computer, executing the command, but I assume you're aware of this.

Comment: As long as `some_cmd` doesn't do anything stupid (and is in the path) I see no problem with it. It's the same as invoking that command line in a shell.

Comment: If the user can control the arguments to the external command being executed, consider avoiding it or sanitize the input.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I suppose the *really* worst case is that `awk` is actually some awk implementation other than `gawk` that gives unexpected results. But `awk` is in Posix, so as long as you code to the standard it should be OK, and `{print $2}` is not a complex program :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - :D :D True, didn't think about that, good point.

Comment: @KirilKirov  & others, some_cmd is hard-coded and is safe command itself. I can't think of any situation where this would cause a problem (other than `awk` not present or `some_cmd` failing). But these are fine with me as popen() will report the failure anyway. As per the comments there's no difference between the above two popen calls whether I do the parsing in C or use awk?

Comment: @SteveJessop I thought it's not going to cause any issue. But it's better to ask wiser people on SO for any subtle issue that may be there ;-)

Comment: I think you should document that your software is running such commands. It depends upon how malicious your user is expected to be (a malicious or stupid user could have a script named `awk` in his `$PATH` which is doing bad things). And you have an additional dependency on `awk`, so better document that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  Point taken. That's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running any "external command" is a slight risk. How big a risk depends on what your application is doing, who has access to that application and what access they have to the machine otherwise. The main problem is that users may circumvent system security by replacing a "command" with something that does something other than that [or "what you expect AND something else"]. This becomes more of an issue if your application has privileges that the regular user doesn't have (or access to something the regular user wouldn't have) and the spawned process inherits those privileges.

Adding `awk` on top of what you are already running doesn't really change things on that account - if the user can alter what `awk` does (typically by placing another program called `awk` at a place that is found before the real `awk`), then the user can probably do that with `some_cmd` too.

It really comes down to "what can someone do that they couldn't do already" and "what damage/benefit could be the outcome of that". If you work in a bank, and the user of this application could transfer large sums of money (or take tiny amounts and accumulate it into an account somewhere) or your code is protecting nuclear missiles, you probably need to think carefully about what this could lead to.

On the other hand, if this is to run on a person's machine, where normally they would have pretty much full access to the machine anyway, and the machine isn't a public webserver that may risk being attacked by foreign users, then the risk is pretty small, right?

Comment: I like the idea of a linux box where *some* users can access the nuclear missiles and others can't :-) `sudo launch --all`, `user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` Presumably in the court martial.

Comment: Well, the maintenance staff that do backups of the map-data and such wouldn't have enough privileges to run `launch`, would they? ;)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _after_ some command... But yes, I think it doesn't really matter much. My worry would be "trojan" versions of `some_cmd` and `awk` - assuming (which you already have explained) the user can't influence what commands are being run.